# Google Maps API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps

It's there a simple way to create a dynamic customizable and administrable Web application using Google Maps and being able to draw routes, I mean, to draw vehicle routes or cycle routes maybe via XML??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps API can do all of that, fortunately, with very little wrapping! At least the JS API, I wrote a layer on top of it with almost no effort.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks my friend, just what I was looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom draw your maps (paths, zones, icons, etc.) using the google maps site and save it to a personal map.

Then you can easily embed that personal map on any website.

You start by clicking on the "My Maps" tab and from there you have all the options you described.  Save the map to an account that can have shared access and the job's accomplished.